# file_put_contents error on existing laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to configure a new laravel project however I always get the following error no matter what:

```
file_put_contents(C:\Users\bla...\Documents\GitHub\project\storage\framework/sessions/yB2Ji8maEDu0fXZLpZ5VBnDzIhLdaeA7aYdVMjOf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I have tried re installing homestead/laravel/vagrant I have also ran the following and more artisan command again and again:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

I have also ran chmod privileges on files/folders inside of my vagrant box but still nothing gets me past this error, any ideas? The project itself is created perfectly fine inside of my vm.

Comment: My guess would be that you are trying to install this on a unix or linux system. Am I right?

Comment: This is on a windows machine but an ubuntu based VM @RiggsFolly

Comment: See `C:\Users\bla...\Documents\......` does that look like a folder likely to exist  on Ubuntu

Comment: Is the site _running_ on Windows or on Linux? Unless you have  web server set up in windows, all paths in the application must be *nix-paths, not Windows paths. Your VM machine doesn't have any access (or knowledge) about your Windows file system.

Comment: This is set up on a windows machine..

Comment: Then what are you using Homestead for? That's a virtual linux server. If you use that, then you most likely are running the site from that (linux) and not Windows, or it would be completely pointless running Homestead.

Comment: See above comment, you SAID this is a Ubuntu VM running on a Windows HOST

Comment: Im using homestead with vagrant with the files mapped from my windows machine to the vm using homestead.yaml, I have another computer set up in the exact same way and it's running fine. I used `vagrant up` within my Homestead folder

Comment: The site (your code) are being executed in the Linux environment. The linux environment doesn't know about the Windows environment. It also can't use Windows file-paths. Every path in your code, _must_ be a path that's available in your VM machine. It has _no idea_ what `C:\Users\bla...` is since that's file path on your _Windows_ drive and doesn't exist in your VM machine.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yeah but my homestead.yaml file links these two together surely?

Comment: That only exposes a windows folder in the guest OS (Ubuntu). Basically, it says that the folder `C:\foo\bar` should be used behind the scenes (the virtual machine application itself) when Ubuntu asks for ex. `/var/www`. Ubuntu only knows about `/var/www` and has _no clue_ about `C:\foo\bar`. That's simply how it works. If it _did_ know about the host (Windows) file system and you used those paths in your PHP application, how would you ever be able to deploy your application on a server?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson probably should have added that this is an Angular/Laravel project

Comment: That doesn't change the fundamental issues with your paths.

Answer (score 3):

Delete all the files in yourProject/storage/framework/sessions, then run `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: That won't solve the issue with the OP using the host OS (Windows) file paths in their PHP application that runs in Homestead.